# managed bean EJB injection

Tags: jsf, ejb, managed-bean, converters

i'm having many managed beans and was wondering if i could create  a UtilClass where i
put my  services calls (@EJB). I've already tried it but i'm having a NullPointerException.
this is how my UtilClass and my managed bean look like:

```
public class UtilClass{
@EJB
private static MyFirstEjbLocal myFirstService;
@EJB
private static  MySecondEjbLocal mySecondService;
//other services
//getters

 }


public class MyManagedBean{
   public String myMethod(){

   UtilClass.getMyFirstService.doSomethingInDB();

   return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do the following, since apparently you are having a lot of services and want to have them grouped together, you can create an "*abstract*" bean and make your managed bean extend such "*abstract*" bean, in this way you can access the EJB's in a structural and safe way, the following code will explain what I mean:

```
public class MyAbstractBean{
  @EJB
  protected MyFirstEjbLocal myFirstService;
  @EJB
  protected  MySecondEjbLocal mySecondService;
  // All your other EJB's here
  ...
  // All other variables and methods you could need
}


public class MyManagedBean
   extends MyAbstractBean{

    public String myMethod1(){

      myFirstService.doSomethingInDB();
      return "";

    }

    public String myMethod2(){

      mySecondService.doSomethingInDB();
      return "";

    }
}
```

Please refer to [JavaEE5 EJB FAQ](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#POJOLocalEJB) if you need to clarify more concepts on the matter.

Comment: that would work .Actually, i'm having a problem with converters and i thought i could make use of my UtilClass in getAsObject method but i'm having a NullpointerException when i use it.

Comment: I think then you are having a problem related to _Injection not being supported for POJO classes_ check the link I gave

Comment: You can only perform injection into a managed class (EJB, servlet, etc.), and in the server, only non-static fields can be injected.  I would recommend using an abstract class as camiloqp suggests.