# EJB Injection in ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, ejb, managed-bean

When a button on my web page is pressed, the controller/listener (`@ManagedBean`) creates 10 new instances in a database. For that to happen, I need a `MyClassFacade` variable (with an `@EJB anotation`) to get different values from the database and for the `.create()` method that persists the new instances in the database.

But, apparently, I am not allowed to inject an `EJB` annotation variable. I don't need that variable to be available in the `xhtml` file. I just need it in the java class controller for my logic.

To add to the confusion, the projects deploys and works just fine about 50% of the time. The other 50% I get an error :

> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean chartView Caused by : com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=ajax.chartView/ejbPulsFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.mycompany.puls.PulsFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.mycompany.puls.PulsFacade,refType=Session into class ajax.chartView: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ajax.chartView/ejbPulsFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
>           at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)

Maybe I can somehow skip the injection of the `@EJB` variable ?
What should I do ?

EDIT : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903356/managed-bean-ejb-injection?rq=1) is a similar question, the solution offered was : create a different java class where it declares all the EJBs and extends the managed bean.

Comment: Not primefaces or java-se related. I improved your tagging

Comment: Show us your EJB interfaces/implementations as well as the managed bean.

Comment: @ujulu I managed to figure it out in the meantime. It was not a problem with  my code but with the IDE (Netbeans) - aparently when you rename a file it does not rename it, but instead creates a copy of the original file and renames it . This is why sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not. When it worked it used the new file , and when it did not it used the old file.

Comment: @ujulu Should I delete the question ? Or post the code as u sugested and leave it ?

Comment: please remove it

Comment: I would say you answer the question yourself. It might help other people in case they face the same problem.